# Python Keyframe Soft Landing Issue

Tags: python, animation, keyframes

So I am writing a script to animate a neutron hitting on a grid & changing trajectory to next spot using 2-3 key frames; one at the origin, one at the landing point, and/or one at the final point the projectile may bounce to. My problem is when using the key frame functionality, these points are animated with a soft landing which does not match the more aggressive "hitting" style of the projectile (neutron).

```py
#create neutron at origin
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(radius=.15, location=(0, 0, 0))
testNeutron = bpy.context.object

#update location
#animate first landing of projectile aka (hit)
testNeutron.location = (x,y,z)
testNeutron.keyframe_insert(data_path = "location", frame = timeofimpact1st)

#update location
#animate second landing of projectile aka (hit)
testNeutron.location = (x2,y2,z2)
testNeutron.keyframe_insert(data_path = "location", frame = timeofimpact2nd)

#bpy.ops.action.interpolation_type(type='LINEAR')
keyframe1 = bpy.data.objects['Neutron'].animation_data.action.fcurves[0].keyframe_points[0]
keyframe1.interpolation = 'LINEAR'

keyframe2 = bpy.data.objects['Neutron'].animation_data.action.fcurves[0].keyframe_points[1]
keyframe2.interpolation = 'LINEAR'
```

I have tried something like this, but it does not resemble a hitting and quick change of direction to the next location. It resembles a soft landing at one location and a relaxing move to the next (followed by another soft landing)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Your problem seems to be that you've animated a sphere that will be called 'Sphere' because that's the default name you get from the mesh add call; but you're trying to modify the interpolation of an object called 'Neutron'.  You either need to add a name change, or use 'Sphere' in the `bpy.data.objects` references.

Your example is hard to follow because you don't include the location settings `(x, y, z)`, `(x2, y2, z2)` or the frame numbers and you've completely left out your rebound keyframe.  I would need all of that to understand why your animation wasn't working.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. In the script, the neutron name is actually 'Sphere', I just put neutron in an effort to make it more readable. (x,y,z) = (6.834/100, -7.567/100, 677.3/100) & timeofimpact1st = 62.33. (x2,y2,z2)=(78.24/100, -47.31/100, 1109.0/100) & timeofimpact2nd = 101.6. This is for a script to read data, so depending on the dataset the variable values (location, timeofimpact) will change. I also have not put anything for the rebound keyframe I am unaware of the term in whole. Thanks again. Any help is much appreciated